# How many requests I can make to Gmail/Google?

Tags: selenium, automation, python-requests

I have one question if someone can answer that, I would really appreciate that.
I am taking screenshots of emails in my Gmail inbox as shown in below picture

https://ibb.co/KNMvFsh

As, these screenshots cannot be taken using Gmail API. So, I am using selenium for this.

So, the question is, How many screenshots in a day I can take from one account? I don't know how much requests I can make until it blocks me?

I don't wanna get blocked and get captcha thing. I am not an experienced guy, relatively new to this. So, I don't have an idea how much requests I can make without getting blocked.

If someone of you know or have any idea, ill be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can potentially make unlimited requests if you use proxies.

Simply add a list of proxies to your GET request and enjoy:

```
proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy, 
              "ftp"   : ftp_proxy
            }

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict)
```

Also for Selenium, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62237578/4420129):

```
PROXY = "1.111.111.1:8080" #your proxy

chrome_options = WebDriverWait.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("gmail.com")
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your response. Can you please clear my small doubt about proxies? My doubt is, if I make request with different IP(through proxy) everytime on same GMAIL Account, would not it detect that how one account is getting accessed from different locations at very short interval of time? @isopach